# C++ Vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, vector

Hi i have problem when run my programm. Have exception "Vector iterators incompatible" on this part of code `backtrack(params, set, results);`

Full code u can see on this link http://liveworkspace.org/code/MjgyND$7

p.s > On MacOS in XCode all working fine, but on VS 2012 (Win7) i have this error..

p.s > On liveworkspace work fine. May be need modify compiler settings?

```
int backtrack(btIData params, std::vector<float> set, std::vector<btNode> &results)
{
    if (reject(params, set)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        accept(params, set, results);
    }

    set = first(params,set);
    while( (set.size() != 0) || reject(params, set)) {
        backtrack(params, set, results);
        set = right(params,set);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message. Also try to debug your code in order to get the exact line of the error.

Comment: Add the code you use to call the function.

Comment: Please provide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your problem.

Comment: your variable name set may conflict with std::set

Comment: Program compiled.I have this error when run ...

Comment: maybe infinite call to backtrack?

Comment: If you give us a piece of code WE can compile [not so much because we actually need to compile it, but that means it's not MISSING the bit that is important - or may be important so we'll ask you for it even if it's not the problem - but we can't know what it is]. In my experience 80% of errors are "not in the posted code".

Comment: Here is my code http://liveworkspace.org/code/MjgyND$7

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/MjgyND$9 with output iteration

Comment: Don't say `x.size() != 0`. Instead, say `!x.empty()`.

Comment: On liveworkspace code working but in VS2012 throw this error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, did you try to use a *debugger*? If so, what did you find? If not, then this is not exactly a "debug my code for me" web site.

Anyway, it is hard to figure out what your code is doing without additional knowledge of application area. And it is pretty messy to debug, since you pass a lot of containers by value.

However, one formal error is fairly obvious. Your `right` and `first` functions will grow the `set` array (from `backtrack`) to the greater size than the size of `params.input` array. E.g. if your `params.input` array has size `5` (as in your test code), your `set` array will grow to size `6`.

This condition in both functions was apparently supposed to restrict the growth of `set` array

```
int l = (int) candiates.size(); // `candiates` is `set`
if (l > params.input.size())
  // Don't grow array
else
  // Grow array
```

but for some reason you used strict comparison `l > params.input.size()` instead of non-strict one `l >= params.input.size()`. This is exactly what allows your `set` array to grow to size `6`, when `params.input` has only `5` elements.

Then later in `getPathSummary` you iterate over the `input` array with index value from `0` to `sets.size() - 1`

```
float getPathSummary(btIData params, std::vector<float> sets)
{
    float summary = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < sets.size(); i++) {
        summary += params.input[i] * sets[i];
    }

    return summary;
}
```

which causes the index to go out of range and the program to crash. I.e. you attempt to access `params.input[5]`, which does not exist.

Out-of-bound access attempts will produce different run-time errors in different debug implementations of standard library. In your case it just happened to be something about "incompatible iterators".

P.S. Stop passing around heavy data structures by value. Use references.

Comment: getIterationData <-this func add root value 0.

Comment: @user1920358: So what? Your original `input` has size `4`. Your `getIterationData` adds a `0` value making `input` size `5`. Later, your `set` acquires size `6` (as I explained above). And then the cycle in `getPathSummary` crashes because `6` is more than `5` (as I explained above).

Answer (score 0):

If the class btNode is defined in another DLL and the template std::vector gets intanciated in that DLL, you might have incompatibilities depending on the version of the standard library used to build your code and the one used to build the external DLL.

But in your case everything seems to live in the same file